# Pythonic/Simplest way to create range of weekday date objects?

Tags: python, datetime

I'm trying to think of the cleanest/pythonic way to create a list of date objects of only weekdays given a start date and an end date. This is what I could come up with:

```
sdate = datetime.date(2013, 9, 1)
edate = datetime.date(2013, 9, 30)
weekdays = [sdate + datetime.timedelta(days=i) 
            for i in range((edate - sdate).days+1) 
            if (sdate + datetime.timedelta(days=i)).weekday() not in (5, 6)]
```

or

```
alldays = (sdate + datetime.timedelta(days=i) for i in range((edate - sdate).days+1))
weekdays = [d for d in alldays if d.weekday() not in (5, 6)]
```

Is something like this considered clean, or am I just being absurd and I should suck it up and create a for loop?

Comment: List comprehension is Pythonic. So go ahead.

Comment: I think either one is reasonable (except for the `alldays` line extending off the right edge of the screen, which you can easily fix by, e.g., putting a newline before the `for`, or creating the range in a separate line in advance).

Answer (score 2):

I'd consider [`dateutil.rrule`](http://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-470fa22b2db72000d7abe698a5783a46b0731b57) (`pip install python-dateutil`):

```
import datetime
from dateutil import rrule

start = datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 1)
end = datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 30)
rule = rrule.rrule(dtstart=start, freq=rrule.DAILY,
    byweekday=[rrule.MO, rrule.TU, rrule.WE, rrule.TH, rrule.FR]
)
rule.between(start, end, inc=True)


[datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 2, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 3, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 4, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 5, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 6, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 9, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 10, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 11, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 12, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 13, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 16, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 17, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 18, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 19, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 20, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 23, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 24, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 25, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 26, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 27, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 30, 0, 0)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Not saying this is necessarily more Pythonic than your approach but sometimes a combination of generators and [itertools](/questions/tagged/itertools) helps make the code more readable without adding overhead, again YMMV

```
from itertools import takewhile, count
import datetime
sdate = datetime.date(2013, 9, 1)
edate = datetime.date(2013, 9, 30)
g = (sdate + datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in count(1))
g = (x for x in g if x.weekday() not in (5, 6))
g = takewhile(lambda x: x <= edate, g)
print list(g)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's anything unreasonable about your code… but if you're using date ranges multiple times, you can definitely make it cleaner by factoring that out into a function. For example:

```
def date_range(start, stop, skip=1):
    daycount = (stop - start).days
    for i in range(0, daycount, skip):
        yield start + datetime.timedelta(days=i)
```

You can make this a one-liner that just `yield from`s something like your original genexpr, but I don't think it's worth it.

Anyway, once you have this, you can just do:

```
weekdays = [d for d in date_range(sdate, edate) if d.weekday() not in (5, 6)]
```

If you're doing other things that require it, you might even want a `timedelta_range` that `date_range` can use:

```
def timedelta_range(start, stop=None, skip=1):
    if stop is None: start, stop = datetime.timedelta(0), start
    r = range(start.days, stop.days, skip)
    yield from (datetime.timedelta(days=i) for i in r)

def date_range(start, stop, skip=1):
    for i in timedelta_range(datetime.timedelta(days=0), stop-start, skip):
        yield start+i
```

(Making a `range`-like function do the magic "optional first argument" bit is always annoying…)